# NameError: name '(function)' is not defined

Tags: python, function, class

I was writing code and came across a certain anomaly in my opinion. I created a primer that reproduces this error.

```py
num2 = 1234
num1 = 123
class.class1():
    def function1(num1, num2):
        t = num1 + num2
        return t

  
    def function2(num1, num2):
        print(function1(num1, num2))


class1.function2(num1, num2)
```

console

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/home/runner/Python/main.py", line 12, in 
> roro.function2(num1, num2)
> File "/home/runner/Python/main.py", line 9, in function2
> print(function1(num1, num2))
> NameError: name 'function1' is not defined

I didn’t find the answer on the Internet and asked the AI in "replit" to solve this problem, but it gave me a “corrected code” that was identical to mine. In general, I'm at a dead end.
Please help. Tell me what am I doing wrong?

I added `self` to every function but it didn't work.

and I did [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50496654/name-function-name-is-not-defined): "The object the function is called on automatically gets passed as `self`.

So if you call `x.add(y)`, self will be `x` and `other` will be `y`"

class

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/home/runner/Python/main.py", line 11, in 
> class1.num1.function2(num2)
> AttributeError: type object 'class1' has no attribute 'num1'

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/home/runner/Python/main.py", line 11, in 
> class1.function2(num1, num2)
> TypeError: class1.function2() missing 1 required positional argument: 'num2'

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/home/runner/Python/main.py", line 11, in 
> class1.function2(num1, num2)
> TypeError: class1.function2() missing 1 required positional argument: 'num2'

Comment: You need to spend some more time with a tutorial like https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few problems with your code.
First, the class declaration:

```
class.class1():
```

Should be:

```
class class1:
```

And you should use self to reference the class member funtions. The final code should be:

```
num2 = 1234
num1 = 123

class class1:
    def function1(self, num1, num2):
        t = num1 + num2
        return t


    def function2(self, num1, num2):
        print(self.function1(num1, num2))

c1 = class1()
c1.function2(num1, num2)
```

I've tested it and it works.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/runner/Python/main.py", line 12, in <module>
    c1.function2(num1, num2)
NameError: name 'c1' is not defined